# get router data outside of router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented my layout like the following, and I want my components (each of them is a separate route) to be inside mat-card-content. But the problem is when I try to change mat-card-title dynamically since it is not inside the router-outlet, I can not get any data.
Is there any approach to achieve this? (without implementing mat-card-header inside of each component)

```html
<mat-card>
   <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{ routerTitle }}</mat-card-title>
       <span>
         here I want to have my router data
       </span>
   </mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

and this is my module routes look like:

```js
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } }
```

and this is the main app-routing:

```js
{
    path: '',
    component: PanelLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./modules/modules.module').then(
            (module) => module.ModulesModule
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
```

When I log `router.snapshot.data.title`, in the parent component, I get an empty object since it is outside of router-outlet.

Comment: Do you have a Service file ? In a service you can centralize some informations that you need in every components.

Comment: Yes, I do have a bunch of service files. so I can access data from a service? getting data from service in the ngOnInit of the layout? does it work? @Alexis

Comment: Yes you can :), your service(s) file(s) is(are) the gate for your shared data. You can create an accessor in the constructor of any component `constructor(private myService: ServiceName){}` and then access to the data in it with a simple `this.myService` in a method or, as you need, in your `ngOnInit`

Comment: yes I know the way to use services in my angular program, I just wonder wether or not I can access router info outside of router-outlet via a service @Alexis

Comment: Have you seen the answer I provided to you ? Is it helping ? @Hossein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can use your service to share data, but in your case, I am not sure it's finally what you need.

From wherever you want, you can subscribe to the `router` events. If you do in your component where you have your `mat-card`, you can change the `routerTitle` directly when route change.

On the constructor of your component, you need to create something like this

```
router.events.forEach(e => {
  if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.title = route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data.title;
  }
});
```

You get all the events of the router (NavigationStart, RouteConfigLoadStart, RouteConfigLoadEnd, RoutesRecognized ... [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Event) a list of all the events), and you just want to know if the navigation is done. Once it is done, you get the value you've passed on your route.

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-78mfh8) to show you how it works